# Help understanding conflicting results from INA190 current sense amp

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, current-sensing

Built a board for a drone that has a few things onboard, though the one that is messing me up is the current sense chip, INA190, though it's most likely not the problem.

Picture 1 show the big yellow battery connector (12v) that feeds the 1mOhm shunt resistor and the other side of the resistor are stitching vias to the power plane (layer 3). This is a 4 layer board. Using an electronic load (wire soldered to the top of the load side shunt) and reading the voltage from the INA190 seems great. I use the electronic load to establish/calibrate the amps/volt.

Where it gets weird - I have brushless motor (BLDC) speed controllers onboard and associated FETs (picture 2). Since the motors can consume up to 15A each (4), I made layer 3 the load/power plane (thinking here is one big trace). As indicated above, stitching vias carry current following the shunt to layer 3, and similar vias (picture 2) carry current to the bottom layer where the FETs are. I'm fairly certain this is where the issues are...

Anyway, I've established using a thrust stand that at a certain RPM, this motor pulls 3A. Using the ESC on this board at the same RPMs, the INA190 essentially says it's pulling 5.5-6A. Technically different speed controllers, so maybe the FETs are the differentiating factor? Not really. I hooked my multimeter (in 10A mode) in-between the battery and the power input of this board (the yellow connector) and ran the test again. This time the INA190 is reading correctly as is the multimeter. You can imagine a few feet of multi-meter wire while hooked up this way, which could introduce resistance.
Even stranger - I hooked this separate battery monitor (uses INA226) inline with the battery and my board (so battery -> 3rd party battery monitor -> my board), similar as above using the multimeter, and the INA190 went back to show the higher incorrect current, BUT this 3rd party battery monitor showed the correct current.

Really confused and don't know enough to pinpoint the issue.

TLDR;

- Test 1) Battery -> PCB = INA190 shows incorrect higher current reading when BLDC motors are running at a known RPM
- Test 2) Battery -> multimeter (10A) -> PCB = INA190 shows correct current reading when BLDC motors are running at a known RPM
- Test 3) Battery -> 3rd party battery monitor -> PCB = INA190 shows incorrect higher current reading when BLDC motors are running at a known RPM, 3rd party battery monitor shows correct current reading.

[image: INA190 + shunt resistor + Vias to load plane]
[image: Brushless motor speed controller FETs + Vias to load plane]

Comment: Schematic please. Have you implemented the filter in Fig 40 of the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina190.pdf), and if so, what are the values and your calculated -3dB frequency vs. PWM fundamental frequency?

Comment: What is the common mode noise level at R4 and which INA gain version is used?

Comment: 25 V/V version. Sadly, I don't have the instruments to measure the noise level, though I suspect its noisy. I didn't implement the filter, though I can see how it would help now.

Comment: Update: Fortunate enough to have enough trace to hack in a pair of 1kOhm resistors and 22nF cap which fixed the issue! Thank you guys for cluing me in on this area of concern.